# Problem with friction

Tags: calculus, physics

Imagine two boxes stacked on top of each other.

The bottom box is larger than the top box and it rests on a surface.

So:

[image]

Between the boxes is a friction force constant $\mu_s$ and between the bottom box and the surface is the friction force constant $0,24$.

What is the maximum force I can pull the bottom box (box 1) with in order for box 2 not to slide.

I have NO idea how to start this problem.

All I got is some gravity forces acting on the boxes and the traction force on the bottom box represented as:

$9,8 \cdot (b_1 + b_2)$ and traction: $0,24 \cdot 9,8 \cdot (b_1 + b_2)$

Comment: What is the force of friction?  It is assumed to be a force on an object that 1) has a direction opposite to the direction of motion and 2) has a magnitude proportional to the normal force exerted from its point of support.  So ask yourself: what is the direction of motion of the smaller box on top, and what is the normal force?

Comment: First of answer me: How do you define friction?

Comment: I define friction has a force in the opposite direction than the force that is pulling it?

Comment: Hint:  Draw the "free body diagrams" of both masses separately, marking also all the relevant frictional forces.  Also nothing to do with calculus.

Comment: Now that is a very common misconception. Friction is the force that opposes "relative" motion between two surfaces. And I emphasize again friction may or may not oppose motion but it always opposes "relative" motion between two surfaces. Now when the force pull the body in the bottom the upper body will have a tendency to go left. How do you think the surface between the two bodies should "react" so as to oppose the relative motion between them.

Comment: Hint: If the pulling force exceeds the maximum static friction force between the boxes, they will start to slide.

Comment: The surface under the upper box is moving to the right so the top box will start moving to the left due to the friction force between the boxes not being strong enough to hold it in place. In other words its vector is pointing right.

Comment: Yes and then you can work it out from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**
For the bottom mass, you have the following force equation in x-axis (why?)

$$T - \mu_s m_{top}g - 0.24 (m_{top}+m_{bottom})g =  (m_{top}+m_{bottom})a \tag{1}$$
where $a$ is the common acceleration if the top body does not slip.

Writing equations for the top mass you have:

$$\mu_s m_{top}g = m_{top}a \implies a \le \mu_sg \quad \text{for not slipping} \tag{2}$$

Use the bound from $(2)$ in $(1)$ to get the maximum force for not slipping.

Comment: Only thing I am wondering...As the friction force between the boxes is pointing in the RIGHT direction and so is T. Why do we subtract that force instead of adding it?

Comment: You need to draw the diagrams of each body separately, then this gets clear.  The friction between boxes appears towards right to the top box (as this is what causes it to move), and the bottom box experiences it towards the left (it is a drag against motion in this case).  They are equal and opposite of course, and always exactly cancel out when you consider both masses together.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "use the bound in 1"?

Comment: Use the limiting value of $a$ obtained above in eqn $(1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't realize how to do that

Comment: You need to work on it yourself if it is homework.  The idea is that there is a maximum friction possible between the blocks, i.e. $\mu_s m_{top} g$.  From $(2)$, if $a > \mu_s g$, friction cannot keep up, and the top block slips.  So we must have $a \le \mu_sg$. Now if this is so, eqn $(1)$ implies that $T$ cannot be too large.  Substitute the maximum value of $a$ in equation $(1)$ to get the maximum value of $T$.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood what you meant, sorry and thank you.

Comment: I'm not supposed to get some fixed number value am I? I just get a clot of stuff if I sub $ \mu_s g $ instead of $a$.

Comment: It remains an expression unless you know the value of both masses and friction coefft.